# Building a url to a STS in a passive scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif

I'm used to program with WIF and the pattern usually goes like this:
- Add a STS Ref
- Set the location of the web that needs to be autorized (or decorate actions in MVC with [Autorize]
- if the user access the "reserved" section, they are redirected to the STS

But let's say I need to actually build a web page that offer the user a choice of STS in order to logon. Not by accessing a page that triggers the redirection by configuration, but by actively loggin in on the page.

If I do this, what would be the form of the url to my STS ? What are the params I need to set to make the user login then redirect to let'S say the index page ?

Answer (score 3):

WIF can help you with this.

Here's a code snippet of what it looks like:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

var signInRequest = new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm)
        {
            AuthenticationType = fam.AuthenticationType,
            Freshness = fam.Freshness,
            Realm = "some realm",
            Context = GetAReturnUrl(),
            HomeRealm = "A Home Realm"

        };
```

Then you can retrieve the URL with:

```
signInRequest.WriteQueryString()
```